# using external php file in html form

Tags: php

I am trying to create simple user registration form. I have an `index.html` file and a `register.php` file. When I click the submit button it goes to the `register.php` page, but nothing happens. There's no error or anything. I have some `echo` statements in `register.php` but they also don't work.

This is the code for `index.html`:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<table width="384" border="1" align="center">
<? echo '<tr><td colspan="2">'.$final_report.'</td></tr>';?>
<tr>
<td width="50%">Username:</td>
<td width="50%"><label>
  <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="30" />
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Password:</td>
  <td><input name="password" type="password" id="password" value="" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Email:</td>
  <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><label>
    <input name="register" type="submit" id="register" value="Register" />
  </label></td>
</tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

This is code for `register.php`:

```
<? 
include_once"config.php";
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$memip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date("d-m-Y");
if($username == NULL OR $password == NULL OR $email == NULL){
$final_report.= "Please complete the form below..";
}else{
if(strlen($username) <= 3 || strlen($username) >= 30){
$final_report.="Your username must be between 3 and 30 characters..";
}else{
$check_members = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` =    '$username'");   
if(mysql_num_rows($check_members) != 0){
$final_report.="The username is already in use!";  
}else{ 
if(strlen($password) <= 6 || strlen($password) >= 12){
$final_report.="Your password must be between 6 and 12 digits and characters..";
}else{
if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$",         $email)){ 
$final_report.="Your email address was not valid..";
}else{
$create_member = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members` (`id`,`username`, `password`,`email`, `ip`, `date`) 
VALUES('','$username','$password','$email','$memip','$date')"); 
$final_report.="Thank you for registering, you may login."; 
}}}}}}
?>
```

Can anyone see the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include_once"config.php"
```

You seem to be missing a space. Either make it `include_once "config.php"` (notice the space in between) or `include_once("config.php")`.

Also you set `$final_report` in `register.php` but I don't see where you are actually printing anything.

**Edit:** I see you are trying to print `$final_report` in `index.php`. This won't work as you expect unless you include the `register.php` code directly into `index.html`. Why don't you just have a single `register.php` file with both the registration script and the HTML code?

Comment: I made my main page as a index.html then I include in it form for registration.If I also include php script in index.html file then I should change it to index.php. I have several pages in a relation with index.html

Comment: You are already using PHP code (`<? echo ... ?>`) in index.html. If that is working, then you shouldn't have any problem adding more code there. (Many web servers will parse HTML files as PHP by default.)